# RxJs operator that behaves like withLatestFrom but waits for value of second stream

Tags: rxjs

Hi I'm looking for an RxJs operator that behaves similar to withLatestFrom, with the exception that it would wait for the second stream to emit a value instead of skipping it. To be claer: I only want emissions when the first stream emits a new value.

So instead of:

```
---A-----B----C-----D-|
------1----------2----|
   withLatestFrom
---------B1---C1----D2|
```

I want this behavior:

```
---A-----B----C-----D-|
------1----------2----|
   ?????????????
------A1-B1---C1----D2|
```

Is there an operator for this?

Comment: That sounds like [`combineLatest()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest).

Comment: @martin combineLatest emits a new value when either source emits a new value. I only want emissions when the first stream emits a new value.

Comment: Maybe like this: `combineLatest(first, second).pipe( distinctUntilKeyChanged(0) )`

Comment: @Smola that's actually a quite clever solution, and simple too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Smola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073629/smola) came up witha nice and clean solution in the comments that simply uses a `distinctUntilKeyChanged` operator:

```
combineLatest(first$, second$)
    .pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged(0))
```

As you can see in the [RxViz](https://rxviz.com) diagram, this produces the desired result:
[image: RxViz Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an operator that does exactly this, but you can achieve those results by combining a high order mapping operator and a `Subject`:

```js
second$ = second$.pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false }));

first$.pipe(
  concatMap(
    firstVal => second$.pipe(
      map(secondVal =>  `${firstVal}${secondVal}`),
      take(1),
    )
  )
)
```

`shareReplay` places a `ReplaySubject` in front on the data producer. This means that it will reply latest `N`(`bufferSize`) values to every **new subscriber**. `refCount` makes sure that if there are no more active subscribers, the `ReplaySubject` in use **won't be destroyed**.

I decided to use `concatMap` as I think it's *safer* for the `ReplaySubject` to have only **one** active susbcriber.

Considering this scheme:

```
---A-----B----C-----D-| first$
------1----------2----| second$
```

When `A` comes in, the `ReplaySubject`(from `shareReplay`) will receive a new subscriber and `A` it will wait until `second$` emits. When this happens, you'd get `A1` and the inner observable will complete(meaning that its subscriber will be removed from the `ReplaySubject`'s subscribers list). `1` will be cached by the `ReplaySubject`.

Then `B` comes in, the newly created inner subscriber will subscribe to `second$` and will receive `1` immediately, resulting into `B1`. Same with `C`.

Now comes an important part: the `ReplaySubject` should have no active subscribers when it receives a new value from its source, so that's why I opted for `take(1)`. When `2` will come, the `ReplaySubject` will have no active subscribers, so nothing happens.

Then `D` arrives and will receive the latest stored value, `2`, resulting into `D2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did this in kotlin using RxJava

```
Observable.merge(
    Observable.combineLatest(streamOne(), streamTwo(), ::Pair).take(1),
    streamOne().skip(1).withLatestFrom(streamTwo(), ::Pair)
).subscribe { // Do your thing }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, that's [join](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/join.html). From your example it isn't clear if you're aming left/right join or inner join.

Oh, sorry. It's clear indeed. You need the semantics of inner join (emits iff data in both joinee is present and otherwise waits).

Comment: But I don't want any emissions when the second stream emits. I think join emits when either  stream emits a new value?

Comment: Either implement `withNextFrom` on your own, or rely on `scan` that checks the past state and in case no new data on the first stream seen, emits exactly the same value thus discarding the update on the second one; `distinctUntilChanged` may help to avoid duplicates.